# What are the protrusions on a front-end bra for?

Tags: body, frontend

Every now and then I come across a car that has parts of its front covered in a leather-like tissue. Finally, I have learned that these things are called [front-end bra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_bra) or front-end cover. The linked Wikipedia article also has some discussion about the rationale behind this cover and how useful or not it is.

However, most of the covers I see also have two protrusions consisting of the same material basically folded up to a triangular shaped bar, as can be seen in the image below ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:1991_BMW_318i_with_hood_bra.jpg)):

[image: BMW with bra]

Unfortunately the Wikipedia article does not explain what those protrusions are for. The only thing I could imagine is that they are thought as some kind of wind deflector to keep the wind shield cleaner and/or provide better functionality of the wipers at higher speeds. Am I right with this idea or is it something else?

Comment: Its to attract another BMW so they can mate...

Answer (score 7):

I like to refer to those as eyebrows, and in the specific image you posted, they are to add some stiffening and down force to the center of the bra so the flat edge against the hood doesn't flap around in the wind.  Since there is nothing to fasten the center of the bra to, the designers had to resort to aerodynamic forces to keep it in place.

Comment: they also double as a bug deflector....

Comment: @Moab, I have heard that, but I tend to reject that hypothesis.

Comment: Considering the possibility of them flapping around like that, which would damage your paint, I consider that a good reason to avoid front end bras like that all together. If you want to actually protect your paint, get some clear paint protection film (also known as a clear bra).

Comment: Front end bra's damage paint finish over time no matter what, but they look cool.

Comment: @JPhi1618 it was humor, but you fell for it.

Comment: @Moab May be humor but many people think that so thanks for bringing it up.